# Cannot Pass Parameters to method in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec-rails

I have written the following code in Rspec to test an update function in one of my controller that updates the records in a table `T` which has say 10 attrtbutes. In update function of my controller I have received parameters by `params[:xyz][:id ], params[:xyz][:attr1] and so on.` So I invoke the function update to update two attributes of table `T`, in Rspec code as follows:

```
it "should update the attributes properly" do    
  put :update, :id=>123, :xyz => {:id => 123, :attr1 => value of attr1, :attr2 => value of attr2}  
end
```

Here I have passed the ID outside because by `rake routes` I have found that ID appears in end of the URL for update function as `controller name/update/id`. In update function of my controller I have received the id by the following code

`params[:xyz][:id] = params[:id] if params[:xyz] and not params[:xyz].key?(:id)`

But this is not working. It is giving the following error.

`` NoMethodError:
       undefined method `key?' for "123":String ``

So if anyone helps me to rectify this problem I will be really grateful. Thank you.

Comment: without knowing what the error is, how can we help?

Comment: show update action code.